# Crucible heating apparatus

Tags: experimental-chemistry

I have seen some heating apparatus for a crucible use a retort stand with a large metal ring attached to the boss head to support the clay triangle as shown below.

[image]

Instinctively, I would have placed the clay triangle on a tripod, however, I see that this has certain advantages, such as being able to adjust the height of the crucible so that it is in the hottest part of the flame.

My question is: **What is the name of this piece of laboratory equipment, I have seen it sometimes referred to as an iron ring, but is there a more formal name?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Iron ring** is a correct term often used for this piece of equipment, according to the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iron_ring_(laboratory)), also [this lab equipment tutorial page](http://www.mreisley.com/tutorials/equipment/supports.html) and in a very comprehensive [pictorial lab equipment guide](http://avogadro.chem.iastate.edu/labmanual/documents/pictorial_guide-163.pdf) from Iowa State University.

Additionally, it is also called an **iron support ring** and a [**retort ring**](http://www.haines.com.au/index.php/lab-equipment/retort-ring-75mm-d-with-bosshead.html).